# Angular 4 - Access to father element view is undefined with @ViewChild

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, viewchild

I need to create a modal to manage errors. So I suppose that the best solution is to put this modal in my **app.component** so that I can use a single modal in my project:

```
<my-dialog #MyErrorDialog>
    ...
</my-dialog>
```

now I need to open this modal in many components or services when an http code occurs but with the reference id:

```
@ViewChild('MyErrorDialog') MyErrorDialogReference: MyDialog;
```

*MyErrorDialogReference* in my child component/service is ***undefined*** because the modal is in the app component.

I don't want to use *@Input/@Output*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `service` as:

**ErrorService**

```
public errorMessage = new Subject<string>();
setErrorMessage(value: string) {
    this.errorMessage.next(value);
}
```

**any other component** *Notify service about error*

```
constructor(public errorService: ErrorService) { }
setMessage(message) { // call this method whenever you get error
    this.errorService.setErrorMessage(message);
}
```

**app.component** *receive error in App component*

```
errorMessage: string;
errorSubscription: Subscription;
constructor(public errorService: ErrorService) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.errorSubscription = this.errorService.errorMessage.subscribe(
        (message) => {
            this.errorMessage = message;
            // open dialog with message
        }
    );
}
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.errorSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```